# searching for hundreds of patterns in huge Logfiles

Tags: c++, partitioning

I have to get lots of filenames from inside a webserver's htdocs directory and then take this list of filenames to search a huge amount of archived logfiles for last access on these files.

I plan to do this in C++ with Boost. I would take newest log first and read it backwards checking every single line for all of the filenames I got.

If a filename matches, I read the Time from Logstring and save it's last access. Now I don't need to look for this file any more as I only want to know last access.

The vector of filenames to search for should rapidly decrease.

I wonder how I can handle this kind of problem with multiple threads most effective.

Do I partition the Logfiles and let every thread search a part of the logs from memory and if a thread has a match it removes this filename from the filenames vector or is there a more effective way to do this?

Comment: This is probably going to be a IO-bound operation more than anything, so I don't think threads are going to help anything here.

Comment: If you have Mathematica you could write something to do this very quickly.

Comment: Don't you think that just reading a logfile into memory and splitting the strings amongst 4 or 8 threads for searching them from memory simultaniously would be a performance boost? This would be the Map Reduce like approach where u use multiple threads for doing the work on memory mapped data, but you have seperated phases for reading and processing the data. this way you don't have to handle any synchronizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using mmap, it will save you considerable hair loss. I was feeling expeditious and in some odd mood to recall my mmap knowledge, so I wrote a simple thing to get you started. Hope this helps!

The beauty of mmap is that it can be easily parallelized with OpenMP. It's also a really good way to prevent an I/O bottleneck. Let me first define the Logfile class and then I'll go over implementation.

Here's the header file (logfile.h)

```
#ifndef _LOGFILE_H_
#define _LOGFILE_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using std::string;

class Logfile {

public:

    Logfile(string title);

    char* open();
    unsigned int get_size() const;
    string get_name() const;
    bool close();

private:

    string name;
    char* start;
    unsigned int size;
    int file_descriptor;

};

#endif
```

And here's the .cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "logfile.h"

using namespace std;

Logfile::Logfile(string name){
    this->name = name;
    start = NULL;
    size = 0;
    file_descriptor = -1;

}

char* Logfile::open(){

    // get file size
    struct stat st;
    stat(title.c_str(), &st);

    size = st.st_size;

    // get file descriptor
    file_descriptor = open(title.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
    if(file_descriptor < 0){
        cerr << "Error obtaining file descriptor for: " << title.c_str() << endl;
        return NULL;
    }

    // memory map part
    start = (char*) mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, file_descriptor, 0);
    if(start == NULL){
        cerr << "Error memory-mapping the file\n";
        close(file_descriptor);
        return NULL;
    }

    return start;
}

unsigned int Logfile::get_size() const {
    return size;
}

string Logfile::get_title() const {
    return title;
}

bool Logfile::close(){

    if( start == NULL){
        cerr << "Error closing file. Was closetext() called without a matching opentext() ?\n";
        return false;
    }

    // unmap memory and close file
    bool ret = munmap(start, size) != -1 && close(file_descriptor) != -1;
    start = NULL;
    return ret;

}
```

Now, using this code, you can use OpenMP to work-share the parsing of these logfiles, i.e.

```
Logfile lf ("yourfile");
char * log = lf.open();
int size = (int) lf.get_size();

#pragma omp parallel shared(log, size) private(i)
{
  #pragma omp for
  for (i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
     // do your routine
  }
  #pragma omp critical
     // some methods that combine the thread results
}
```

Comment: That looks like what I was thinking about to do. So omp will parralellize the loops for me after i map data to memory. That saves me a lot of work and is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!!

Comment: No problem, glad I was of help!

Comment: Just thought I'd add that you should attribute the size variable as firstprivate(size), not shared, to avoid a data race condition in the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the logfile into a database table (SQLite ftw). One of the fields will be the path.

In another table, add the files you are looking for.

Now it is a simple join on a derived table. Something like this.

```
SELECT l.file, l.last_access FROM toFind f
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT file, max(last_access) as last_access from logs group by file
) as l ON f.file = l.file
```

All the files in toFind will be there, and will have last_access NULL for those not found in the logs.

Comment: And this will be really fast?

Comment: Yes. You will need to add an index to l.file and f.file. You also get the ability to do further data manipulation if you need it. The import will be the slowest part, but as Joey said, this is going to be IO bound anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is some days ago already but I spent some time writing code and working with SQLite in other projects.

I still wanted to compare the DB-Approach with the MMAP Solution just for the performance aspect.

Of course it saves you a lot of work if you can use SQL-Queries to handle all the data you parsed. But I really didn't care about the work amount because I'm still learning a lot and what I learned from this is:

This MMAP-Approach - if you implement it correctly - is absolutely superior in performance. It's unbelievable fast which you will notice if you implement the "word-count" example which can be seen as the "hello world" for MapReduce Algo.

Now if you further want to benefit from SQL-Language the correct approach would be implementing your own SQL-Wrapper that uses kind of Map-Reduce too by the means of sharing queries amongst threads.

You could perhaps share Objects by ID amongst threads, where every thread handles it's own DB-Connection. It then queries Objects in it's own part of the dataset.

This would be much faster than just writing things to SQLite DB the usual Way.

After all you can say:

MMAP is the fastest way to handle string processing
SQL provides great functionality for parser-applications but it slows down things if you don't implement a wrapper for processing SQL-Queries